# How to make a website on Ruby on Rails using Locomotive CMS (or any other) ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

I need to make a simple website - some info, articles, photos and videos. I want it to use Ruby on Rails. This is my first project using RoR.

As long as I found I have to use CMS+host. Locomotive CMS + Heroku host looks nice to me, but if you know the better (faster) way of making it work I will appreciate your help.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, and probably too in-depth for SO (not to mention they don't love opinion based questions).  I'd try googling a tutorial or checking out the Locomotive home page.

Comment: Yeah: I don't think it's possible to give a specific & verifiably correct answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

For the beginning look at

['Getting started with Locomotive'](http://doc.locomotivecms.com/guides/get-started/requirements) and ['How to build a website with Locomotive CMS from scratch'](http://www.tommyblue.it/2011/02/28/how-to-build-a-website-with-locomotive-cms-from-scratch/)